# Stored two dataframes in alist, performed operations on them but original df remained unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two dataframes called a and b.  I store them in a list. 
I then iterate through each item in list to drop columns with all null values and change the dataframes inplace. Then I perform an inner merge on the two dfs.

However, when I check the shape of the merged df, it has all the columns that were previously dropped from each of the original dataframes.

Please, can someone advise why this is happening? Is it because a copy of dataframe is being created when I store it in a list.

Thank you.

```
a['one'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a['two'] = np.nan

b = pd.DataFrame()
b['three'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b['four'] = np.nan

lis = [a, b]
for item in lis:
    item = item.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
    print(item.shape)
This prints (5,1) for both

c = pd.merge(a, b, left_on= 'one', right_on='three', how='inner')
c.shape
This print(5,4) which I expect to be (5,2)
```

Comment: Please post your code or a [MCVE] of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead, use the `inplace` parameter of dropna instead of re-assigning:

```
lis = [a, b]
for item in lis:
    item.dropna(axis=1,how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Please can you explain why this works instead of re-assigning

Comment: I believe this is a varible scoping issue.  Because item is defined in the for loop, you are writing to seperate memory after the dropna.   However, using "inplace=True" seems to allow update the current memory allocation.   Actually, this is the first time I've see this difference in the function of re-assigning to the same variable versus using inplace=True.

Comment: @Moshee because for each iteration in the loop `for item in lis:` the name `item` is a a pointer to the same object being pointed to in the list named `lis`.  When within the loop you do `item = item.dropna(axis=1,how='all')`, it is the `dropna` that is producing a copy and assigning that copy to the name `item`.  That effectively overwrites the name `item` and that name no longer points to the same object as in the list but in stead the copy produced by `dropna`.

Comment: By using `dropna` with `inplace=True` you are telling `dropna` to **not** produce a copy but instead alter the object that is being pointed to.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = pd.DataFrame()
ida = id(a)
a['one'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a['two'] = np.nan

b = pd.DataFrame()
idb = id(a)
b['three'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b['four'] = np.nan

lis = [a, b]
lis = [x.dropna(axis='columns',how='all', inplace=False) for x in lis]
idlis = [id(x) for x in lis]

print(ida)
print(idb)
print(idlis)
```

OUTPUT

```
118567488
118567488
[148747432, 148749840]
```

INSTEAD DO:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = pd.DataFrame()
ida = id(a)
a['one'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a['two'] = np.nan

b = pd.DataFrame()
idb = id(a)
b['three'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b['four'] = np.nan

lis = [a, b]
lis = [x.dropna(axis='columns',how='all', inplace=False) for x in lis]

from functools import reduce
c = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, left_on= 'one', right_on='three', how='inner'), lis)
```